# How to detect MOSFET's open or not

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, fet

In case Vgs is supplied and equal or above of its threshold level so that I expect it's open, but how about a fault occured which I don't know, how can I understand it's open or not by looking on its Vds voltage?

Comment: In circuit or test it on the bench?

Comment: @winny on the bench

Comment: If your Vgsth is low enough and/or the diode mode on your multimeter has high enough compliance voltage, I would normally measure the body diode Vds, "measure"/charge the gate Vgs, measure the Vds again which should now read 0 V due to open channel. "Measure"/discharge the gate Vsg and check that Vds is back to one diode drop.

Comment: I appreciate, how about in circuit I've been really wondering. Thanks btw

Comment: It's impossible to answer since you don't specify N-chan or P-chan ….and what does 'open' mean? Define your device and configuration better, what current is flowing and whether you expect the device is conduction or non-conducting or ON/OFF if its a switch. In the simplest of cases you can usually just measure Vds to understand an ON/OFF condition. You can do that with a multimeter.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I have noticed that some people use the term "open" for conducting, which is in direct conflict with "open" as in "open circuit" (not conducting) as we use in North America, at least. It would be better to use some other term.

Threshold voltage is specified at a given Id. So if you apply a constant current (with limited voltage) or simply connect a properly selected resistor from drain to supply rail and then apply Vgs(th) you should see a Vds that results in a higher current than the specified for Vgs(th).

For example, if Vgs(th) is specified as 2V with Id = 250uA you could use a 20K resistor to 10V. Then apply 2V and Vds should be less than 5V. I picked the resistor for a 5V drop (half the presumed supply) at 250uA current.

When Vgs = 0 (assuming enhancement mode transistor) the Vds should be close to the supply voltage.

The gate current in both cases should be within specifications (probably too low to easily measure).

Example schematic for a Device Under Test that is an N-channel enhancement-mode MOSFET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzpkVi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That will detect most gross faults with a MOSFET.

Comment: Are these technical people using "open" to mean conducting? Or beginners? Because I could see how beginners would envision the switch as a door or gate where being open lets things through.

Comment: @DKNguyen Honestly I'm not sure but it's consistent enough that I think it's a literal translation from another language or languages. Many folks hide their country so it's hard to get a firm idea.